# Delphi 5: Embedding a Software Cert in the final EXE's automatically

Tags: delphi, ssl-certificate, delphi-5

I use a Software Certificate for my installation files but would also like it to be embedded in my final Delphi5 program files. I know I can run some command line switch to do this (don't remember exactly what it is since the installation program does it automatically).

I would like to have it embedded in the program when I do a final build. Is there any way to automate this when doing a final build on a project in Delphi5? Might as well get my money's worth from the cert.

Comment: Use signtool from the MS toolset

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can this be done automatically as the project is being built from within Delphi5?

Comment: No. You have to script that yourself. Write a script to build at command line with dcc32. Later versions of Delphi support build actions.

Comment: I don't remember if D5 supported post-build events, but I don't believe it did, which would mean that it isn't possible from within the IDE.

Comment: @KenWhite no, it did not. Build events are part of the Galileo IDE, which Delphi migrated to in D8.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Delphi 5 IDE provides no tools to modify the executable post-build. Later versions of Delphi offer post-build actions. But not Delphi 5.

It is possible to create an IDE plugin that will perform post-build actions. Tools like madExcept and EurekaLog do exactly that for similar reasons.

In order to sign the executable you might use signtool from the MS tool chain. That's what you need to execute after the build.

Personally I am not sure it is that critical for you to sign the executable from IDE builds. You don't need it signed to debug. In your position I would make sure that my release builds were scripted using the command line compiler. At which point signing the executable is a natural task and easy to tack on to the end of the script.

Comment: Specifically `IOTAIDENotifier50.AfterCompile`

Comment: Thanks, all.I have a new app that used a different installer that does the cert stuff for me. I noticed that with that app, neither the download or Windows complained when being installed or run afterward. The older app without the embedded cert in the installation, if embedded with the installer or command line when I upload new updates might indeed work the same way. I mean, no complaints from Windows on installation is a given, no complaints from windows on running might end up being the same as my newer app. Thanks, all.